# Can we know last read and write's usage's date and time of object in ceph?

Tags: ceph

IS their any function or class from where last read or write usage of objects can be known in ceph?

can we also see the last usage of a month or year?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [rados_read_op_stat](http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/rados/api/librados/#Cephgroup__librados__h__obj__op_1gac306f89b05d84ed0c83342a60c746ca7) function of the librados API can be used to query the last modification time and the size of an object.

The **stat** sub-command in [rados](http://ceph.com/docs/master/man/8/rados/) can conveniently be used to test it:

```
$ rados --pool rbd put FOO /etc/group 
$ rados --pool rbd stat FOO
rbd/FOO mtime 2015-03-24 15:04:47.000000, size 1253
```

Ceph does not collect usage statistics on objects, except for the cache tier which needs to know what objects have not been modified in the past hours and demote them to a slower / less expensive pool. It is however probably not what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. Actually  I wanted to apply over-replication and under-replication strategies according to their past usage. want to create a function where system will migrate object automatically  to appropriate pools.I will create 3 pools and set object replica as minreplica_pool and maxreplica_pool.                                                                                     Is their any way to do this inside source-code?                                                                                                                                                                      Thanks

Comment: This is a different topic. It looks like you're after something like http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/rados/operations/cache-tiering/ right ?